# jQuery display each box at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to learn jQuery and I have this case, I have 3 slides, each slide has some boxes and I want to display them one by one by adding the class `.show`.

The thing should work like this:

1. show boxes on the first slide one by one
2. after all are showed, i want to wait 1 second and do the same for the second
3. repeat, but after show I want to show first slide again.

```js
$('.slide').each(function() {      
  var $childrens = $(this).children();      
  $childrens.each(function() {
      $this.addClass('show');
  });  
});
```

Can someone explain me how to do this?

Here is what I tried.
http://jsbin.com/jigoku/22/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Sounds like a good exercise to learn, people will be happier if you include your code inside of the question itself instead of just a link however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used recursion in a few places here to facilitate the delay in showing the slides.  Your code is solid but it runs near-instantly so I don't think you get the effect you are going for.

`showSlideItems` is responsible for adding the `show` to each child of the slides.  It waits 200ms and displays the next child.

`slideDelay`  takes all slides and goes through them, adding a 1 second wait after all children of one slide is shown.

`showSlides` is responsible for grabbing all our slides and resetting their children so we can loop after both of the above functions complete.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp5vwpqn/) example

**javascript**

```
function showSlides(){
  var slides = $('.slide');
  $('.slide i').removeClass('show');
  slideDelay(slides.toArray());
}

function slideDelay(slides) {
  var slide = slides.shift();

  showSlideItems($(slide).children().toArray(), function(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
      if(slides.length > 0){
        slideDelay(slides); 
      }else{
        showSlides();
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

function showSlideItems(slideItems, callback) {
  if(slideItems.length === 0) {
    callback();
    return;
  }

  var slideItem = slideItems.shift();
  $(slideItem).addClass('show');
  setTimeout(function(){ showSlideItems(slideItems, callback) }, 200);
}

showSlides();
```

**html**

```
  <div class="slide">
    <i>one</i>
    <i>two</i>
    <i>three</i>    
  </div>  

  <div class="slide slide-2">
    <i>four</i>
    <i>five</i>
    <i>six</i>
    <i>seven</i>
  </div>  

  <div class="slide slide-3">
    <i>eight</i>
    <i>nine</i>
    <i>ten</i>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
.slide{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.slide i {
  display: none;
}
```